# Complex numbers with small modulus

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $p$ be a complex number with $|p|<1/10$. How can one prove that there exists a bounded sequence of complex number $(z_n)$ with $z_0=0$ such that $z_{n+1}=z_n^2 + p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick any $r>0$ with $r^2+|p|\le r$ (e.g., $r=\frac15$.)  Then, prove by induction that $|z_n|\le r$ for all $n$:
$$
|z_n|\le r \Rightarrow
|z_{n+1}|=|z_n^2+p|\le |z_n|^2+|p|\le r^2+|p|\le r.
$$